I can't correctly Proxy Pass an Nginx Stream to my Node Service
I have created the following config file for Nginx:
stream {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tcp_access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/tcp_error.log;

    upstream tcp_backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen 587;
        proxy_pass tcp_backend;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}

Nginx -t reports all in order and the file is definitely being included on the top level.
I have a NodeJS App running smtp-server (https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/)
** Please note the console.log.
const setupSMTPServer = (port) => {
  const server = new SMTPServer({
    authOptional: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    secure: false,
    key: tlsOptions.key, // This is a valid LetsEncrypt key
    cert: tlsOptions.cert, // This is a valid LetsEncrypt Fullchain
    onAuth: async (auth, session, callback) => {
        console.log('Auth Attempt');
        // Redacted
    },
    onData(stream, session, callback) {
      console.log('onData Received');
      let data = "";
      stream.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      stream.on("end", async () => {
        parseEmail(data).then((parsedData) => {
          console.log('Received instruction to send email');
        });
      });
    },
  });
  server.listen(9001, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`SMTP server listening on port 9001`);
  });
};

When I attempt to connect via port 587 over TLS, I see the connection attempt being logged in the /var/log/nginx/tcp_access.log with no errors reported in the /var/log/nginx/tcp_error.log file.
The Node service reports no attempted connections whatsoever, almost asthough the Stream has not performed the Proxy Pass correctly. I am unable to perform any diagnosis beyond seeing that Nginx is receiving the connection, and therefore I am not sure what I should be fixing in order to get this SMTP server to be working.
When using an SMTP Testing tool I get this response:
<< 421 d80c8d0ecdbf You talk too soon
ERROR: d80c8d0ecdbf You talk too soon

I have tried disabling the reverseDNSLookup but that made no difference, please don't mark this as duplicate unless it truly is.

did you start smpt server (where is setupSMTPServer called), do you see console.log(\SMTP server listening on port 9001`)`

@traynor Yes, that is the only log that is outputting.

Because of my lack of knowledge here, I did not realise that the flag proxy_protocol is intended to be used in the case described here:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/
Setting proxy_protocol to no (or by omitting it) the issue was resolved as it is now directly forwarding the request to the proxy destination.
Here is the resulting config file that works:
stream {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tcp_access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/tcp_error.log;

    upstream tcp_backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen 587;
        proxy_pass tcp_backend;
        proxy_protocol off;
    }
}

